# como saber que numero de fila esta posicionado en vb en un ciclo foreach?

Tags: vb.net

como saber que numero de fila esta posicionado en `vb` en un for each?
estoy intentando de la forma `row.CurrentRow.Index` pero me dice:
 No se encuentra el miembro público 'CurrentRow' en el tipo 'DataGridViewRow'.

```
    Dim ultimo = Datos.Rows(Datos.Rows.Count - 1)
    For Each row In Datos.Rows
        Dim fecha1 = row.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
        Dim fecha2 = row.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
        If row.Cells(4).Value.ToString() <> "" And row.Cells(5).Value.ToString() <> "" Then
            If row.CurrentRow.Index <> ultimo Then
```

Comment: `midatagrid.CurrentRow.Index;` así se obtiene la fila seleccionada de un `DataGrid` , no es necesario iterar con un `for each`

Comment: no, pero dentro de un ciclo foreach como?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtenerlo con:

```
Datos.Rows.indexOf(row)
```

Ejemplo:

```
     For Each row In Datos.Rows
        Write(Datos.Rows.IndexOf(row) & " = " & row)`
```